# Wordpress- get value of $_REQUEST when submitted to post.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce on wordpress and have subscribed to a filter to add some menu options to the "Order Actions" list in the top right hand corner of an order.

This form submits to `post.php` with a select name of `wc_order_action`.
How can I grab the selected value?
I've done a `print_r($_REQUEST)` and apart from the 2 query string parameters, there is nothing else listed.

Comment: Just a thought - make sure that your request is not somehow getting redirected before it gets to post.php, which would drop any POST variables. It may also be helpful if you could add some of the form's code.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to work it out i think. I'm new to Wordpress and there is something funky going on with the `POST` variables becoming unset (or some `Header:` functions redirecting perhaps). `print_r` didn't work, but I used my plugin to get the value before the template was applied and I can see the value now.